# Closed form for a sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, factorial

Please, i need help with this example, step by step.

Calculate the value of the next summation, i.e. express simple formula without the sum:

$$\sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 5} \frac{6^{n_2-n_4} (-7)^{n_1}}{n_1! n_2! n_3! n_4!}$$

> I think the formula is

$\sum_{n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 = n} = \frac{n!* x^{n_1} * x2^{n_2} * x3^{n_3}* x4^{n_4}}{n2! n2! n3! n4!}$

I don't know how to proceed, i stuck here.

Here is prtscr: http://prntscr.com/l8gluf

Comment: Can we assume $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$ are non-negative?

Comment: @NobleMushtak yes

Comment: I edited the first expression to match the image you link to, but I don't know what the second is supposed to be. Where do the $x$'s come from? There is no $x$ in the original expression.

Comment: @JairTaylor the formula I have done, universalized

Comment: Please explain more clearly and write the complete equation.  What you have is not correct.  Perhaps you mean to write the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: The summation only has a few terms in it, you can find them all and do the addition. The second summation makes no sense at all. I don't know what "prtscr" is, and I'm not inclined to go chasing things offsite – if you want to ask a question here, then the question should be here, not somewhere else.

Comment: @JairTaylor exactly, I think it should be multinomial theorem. But 
I do not know how to proceed. Look on screen, its original example

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, i just print screen the original. We will try to deal only with the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consider the *[multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Sum_of_all_multinomial_coefficients)* in the form
\begin{align*}
\left(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\right)^5&=\sum_{{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=5}\atop{n_j\geq 0, 1\leq j\leq 4}}
\binom{5}{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4}x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}x_3^{n_3}x_4^{n_4}\\
&=\sum_{{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=5}\atop{n_j\geq 0, 1\leq j\leq 4}}\frac{5!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!n_4!}x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}x_3^{n_3}x_4^{n_4}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain applying (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=5}\atop{n_j\geq 0, 1\leq j\leq 4}}}& \color{blue}{\frac{6^{n_2-n_4} (-7)^{n_1}}{n_1! n_2! n_3! n_4!}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{5!}\sum_{{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=5}\atop{n_j\geq 0, 1\leq j\leq 4}}\frac{5!}{n_1! n_2! n_3! n_4!} (-7)^{n_1}6^{n_2}1^{n_3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n_4} \\
> &=\frac{1}{5!}\left(-7+6+1+\frac{1}{6}\right)^5\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{933\,120}}
> \end{align*}

Comment: I only have one question, what specifically means $1 / 5!$ ?

Comment: @MarekMarke: $\frac{1}{5!}=\frac{1}{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}=\frac{1}{120}$. We put this factor in front of the sum as compensation for the factor $5!$ that was put inside the sum in order to obtain a proper representation of the multinomial coefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.  The multinomial theorem is

$$(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_k)^n = \sum_{n_1 + \cdots + n_k = n} {n \choose n_1, \ldots, n_k} x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} \cdots x_k^{n_k}$$

Now let $k=4$, $n=5$ and find values of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ to make the right-hand side summand look a bit like the summand in your expression.  Note that $${n \choose n_1, \ldots, n_k} = \frac{n!}{n_1! \cdots n_k!}$$ so you get the $n_1!n_2!n_3!n_4!$ in the denominator for "free"...

Comment: thanks, my n must be equal 5... $n_1, ....n_4 = 5$

Comment: Ah, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can i do this with expression?

$$\sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 5} \frac{5! *(-7)^{n_1} * 6^{n_2} * 1^{n3} * (1/6)^{n_4}}{n_1! n_2! n_3! n_4!}$$

What next? I just put value into original expression